# clear content of textarea by pressing a specific key

Tags: javascript, textarea

I need to clear content of textarea each time user press the ENTER key.

```js
$("#write").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    $(this).value = "";
    $(this).html = "";
    $(this).text = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="write"></textarea>
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get the value

```
$("#write").keyup(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done correctly but the missing part only is `$(this)[0].value="";` 
when you use `val()` then select object if you use `value` then get into the object and use method that is `$(this)[0]`